# Add a button to save the picture in AIR or AS3

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air

I tried I try to add a button for interface to download the image in the phone folder in AIR or AS3
Or make a photo wallPaper for phon.
Can anyone help me??
And experience it in the attached file .

[image]